# How do I return data as a Key & Value pair from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I'm trying to return a JSON object with a Key,Value pair, both of which are seperate columns in my MySQL table.

So the MySQL table Looks (simplified 1000%) like this:

```
+-----------------+---------------------+
|      Email      |   ProfilePicture    |
+-----------------+---------------------+
| john@email.com  | https://someurl.com |
| jane@email.com  | https://foobar.com  |
| bobby@email.com | https://random.com  |
+-----------------+---------------------+
```

And I want a JSON object like

```
{
"john@email.com":"https://someurl.com",
"jane@email.com":"https://foobar.com",
"bobby@email.com":"https://random.com"
}
```

I could build it up as a string in MySQL by looping through the table and concat everything together, then just parse it in JS. I know that. But it seems messy, and I know there must be some built in functions for this in PHP. I just don't know them.

All my other PHP/MySQL pairings are using mysqli_fetch_assoc and json_encode in the PHP as they don't need the JSON Key to change dynamically only the value.

The eventual JSON object is being returned from a JavaScript function, so I am happy with a fix any where along the chain from JavaScript (or jQuery), to PHP, to MySQL Procedure, and back along.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use PDO to connect the database, you can use something like...

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT Email, ProfilePicture FROM users");
$data  = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
$out = json_encode($data);
```

The `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` uses the first column returned as the key and the second column as the value.

Sticking to mysqli

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT Email, ProfilePicture FROM users");
$data = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[$row['Email']] = $row['ProfilePicture'];
}
$out = json_encode($data);
```

MySQLi version - slightly shorter...

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT Email, ProfilePicture FROM users");
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$out = array_column($data, 'ProfilePicture', 'Email');
$out = json_encode($data);
```